# How do I save form data to sql with jquery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have tried number solutions and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have the following input element:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-layout="fixed" class="pull-right" value="1">
```

just before my closing body tag I have the following jquery

```
<script>
  $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
  var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
     if(checked){
       var value = $(this).val();
         $.post('mysqlfunc.php', { value:value }, function(data){
              if(data == 1){
              }
         });
     }
  });
</script>
```

In mysqlfunc.php file I have

```
<?php
    include "../../inc/config.php";
    include "../../inc/funcs.php";
    @mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
    @mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( "Unable to select database");
    include "../../inc/userauth.php";

    if ($_POST && isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);
    $sql = "UPDATE members SET fixed = '".$value."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['uid']."'";
    } else {
    }
?>
```

My expectation is when I click the input checkbox, a value "1" is saved into the  "members" table in the "fixed" column where the username is equal to the session uid.

I can echo the uid, so that is working. Its not giving any errors, so its connecting to the database it seems. Yet checking the input textbox, does not change the value in the database.

I get no js errors at all, I get no php errors, just not saving.

What am I doing wrong? Example working code if at all possible would be very helpful.

Comment: have you included jquery lib ? Whats your js error?

Comment: "I get no js errors at all, I get no php errors, just not saving."

Comment: Did you try executing the raw query? Try `echo $sql;`, copy the output and execute it in PHPMyAdmin or post it here. Could imagine that the query is wrong, since you have no SQL Error handling, you wouldn't notice

Comment: `echo "UPDATE members SET fixed = '".$value."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['uid']."'"` echo the query and run it in browser.

Comment: If I echo it (I have to remove the if statements as no value is passed if I run the php file directly) - it returns

UPDATE members SET fixed = '' WHERE username='myusername'

If I add the value of 1 to fixed, it runs perfectly in PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Is your `$.post` getting called??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in your script is wrong.

```
var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
```

change it to

```
var checked = $(this).is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 2):

You forget to execute your query use `mysql_query`

```
$sql = "UPDATE members SET fixed = '".$value."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['uid']."'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of jquery you used ? And check if post request really done or not  Try using `.prop` :

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
  var checked = $(this).prop('checked'); //<---- Here
  if(checked){ // here returned true or false
     var value = $(this).val();
     $.post('mysqlfunc.php', { value:value }, function(data){
          if(data == 1){
          }
     });
  }
});
```

**or**....

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){      
  if( this.checked ){ // <-- just checked directly
     var value = $(this).val();
     $.post('mysqlfunc.php', { value:value }, function(data){
          if(data == 1){
          }
     });
  }
});
```

And like @Saty said, put `mysql_query($sql);` to execute those query.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code will look like.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){              
        $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
          var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
             if(checked){
               var value = $(this).val();
                 $.post('mysqlfunc.php', { value:value }, function(data){
                      if(data == 1){
                      }
                 });
             }
          });
    });
```

And You missed to execute SQL so, your PHP code will look like.

```
<?php
include "../../inc/config.php";
include "../../inc/funcs.php";
@mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
@mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( "Unable to select database");
include "../../inc/userauth.php";

if ($_POST && isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);
    $sql = "UPDATE members SET fixed = '".$value."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['uid']."'";
    mysql_query($sql);
} else {
}
?>
```